# Django Form output/Error Checking issue

Tags: django

I have a model that contains an integer field

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

Whenever I display or input data to this model I want to do so in octal.  When I populate my edit form I do this:

```
number = oct(numberObject.number).replace('Oo','')
```

When I go to the edit form it prepopulates with exactly what I want but when I try to do error checking after submitting the form to avoid having that number occur twice I get a problem because number is in self.changed_data and therefore I'm getting the error that this number already exists (basically it's finding itself and saying it is a duplicate)

I can't think of a way to figure out whether I'm trying to change the number to one that already exists or if I'm just submitting the number without changing it.

My form/validation code:

```
class NumberForm(ModelForm):
    number = forms.CharField(max_length = 10)

    def clean_number(self):
        """Ensures the new  Number is unique
        """
        enteredNumber = self.cleaned_data['number']

        changedFields = self.changed_data
        if number.objects.filter(number__exact = int(enteredNumber,8)):
            if 'number' in changedFields:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Error")
        return int(enteredNumber,8)

    class Meta:
        model = Number
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I also tried removing the .replace('Oo','') but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you include your form and validation code?

Comment: Added form/validation code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be editing an existing object, right?
I would simply exclude it from the result set:

```
def clean_number(self):
    """Ensures the new  Number is unique """
    enteredNumber = int(self.cleaned_data['number'], 8)

    queryset = Number.objects.filter(number=enteredNumber)
    if self.instance is not None and self.instance.pk is not None:
        queryset = queryset.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)

    if queryset.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Error")
    return enteredNumber
```

Using the `.exists()` method avoids loading the object from the database, should one exist.

By the way, this form won't ensure you cannot create duplicates. Two threads may run the validation code at the same time, accept the same value, then proceed to saving their respective object with that value.
If you want to be sure you don't have duplicates, you must do so at the database level (by passing `unique=True` to the field on the model).

Comment: Could you give me a quick explanation of the self.instance I'm not entirely sure what that's doing.

Comment: That's the object that is being edited (or either None or an empty instance if you are creating a new object). It's given to the form when it is instanciated by the view.